# What is the workflow of Webpush?

Tags: push-notification

I am trying to understand how webpush works. For now I see the next steps:

1. A User visits a site.
2. Some JS code is executed to get permission to send notifications from the site to the user.
3. User presses "Allow".

However, I can't understand what is next. In particularly, when on site we have a new message how will the User get notified about it? Does some application on user side with some interval makes requests to our site to check if there are new messages? Or how? As I understand internet our site can not send messages to user because of firewalls and NAT. Please, explain.

Answer (score 1):

For detailed description you'd better to read the document by Google.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/how-push-works

Here is a brief description.

## Players

- **Push Server**: external service (e.g. provided by Google) that delivers push notification to user's browser.
- **App Server**: a server application you serve, send push notification to push server
- **Service Worker**: a javascript code you supply, waiting for push notification and handle received notification, even when user closed your site itself.

## Steps

1. A user visit your site
2. You register a service worker to browser.
3. You request user a permission for push notification (and user permit, hopefully)
4. You get a endpoint to send PN, and also exchange information for encryption and authorization.
5. You send information above to your application server.
6. Your app server send PN to push server (endpoint you received at 4)
7. Push server deliver PN to user's browser. You don't need to know how they deliver, like native PN for iOS or Android.
8. Browser kicks your service worker.
9. Your service worker handle PN and show notification